# Store VM User First Name + VM User Last Name as Joomla Full Name

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

This is a Virtuemart specific question, and I have also posted this question on the official Virtuemart forum, but I have not yet had any replies. This is why I post my question here also, hoping someone might know the answer.

I´m using Virtuemart v.2.0.26d

It seems that when a customer creates a new profile via the Virtuemart registration form or via order creation then the user´s email is stored as Joomla user "Full Name"
Instead I would like it to store Virtuemart first name + last name as Joomla "Full Name"

Does anyone know how to accomplish this or which file I need to look into to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab vendors name(see the table names below) to joomla full name the just fetch the vendor name and add it to **'_users'** table *name* and *username* are the needed column there. (joomla 2.5)

Or in opposite case,

Dont know about VM 2.0 but in VM 2.6 while a user uploads a product at table 
**'_virtuemart_vendors_en_gb'** and  **'_virtuemart_vendors'** stores data about product uploader.So either make a column there and find out the registration functionality add the full username there or at update the *vendor_name* in **'_virtuemart_vendors'** and *vendor_store_name* in **'_virtuemart_vendors_en_gb'**.

Thanks